# Why isn't this local integer able to modify a global constant?

Tags: python

I have been making this Hangman game in Python. The problem is in the play_hangman function. Everytime a guess occurs, the constant "guesses" increments by one. I want it to print out "%s guesses left!" where I get %s from a global constant (MAX_GUESSES) subtracted by a local constant (guesses). However it seems to not be working, and it continues to spit out "6 guesses left" when it should increment downward. Any suggestions?

```
   # CONSTANTS
MAX_GUESSES = 6

# GLOBAL VARIABLES 
secret_word = 'claptrap' 
letters_guessed = []

# From part 3b:
def word_guessed():
    '''
    Returns True if the player has successfully guessed the word,
    and False otherwise.
    '''
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    for i in secret_word:
        if i in letters_guessed:
            continue
        else:
            return False        
    return True


def print_guessed():
    '''
    Prints out the characters you have guessed in the secret word so far
    '''
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    blanklist = []
    for i in secret_word:
        if i in letters_guessed:
            blanklist.append(i)
        else:
            blanklist.append("-")
    blanklist_string = "".join(blanklist)
    return blanklist_string

def play_hangman():
    # Actually play the hangman game
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    global MAX_GUESSES
    # Put the mistakes_made variable here, since you'll only use it in this function
    mistakes_made = 0
    guesses = 0
    guesses_left = MAX_GUESSES - guesses

    while word_guessed() is False:
        print print_guessed()
        print "%s guesses left!" % guesses_left
        letter_choice = raw_input("Choose a letter:")
        if letter_choice not in secret_word:
            mistakes_made += 1
            print "you have made %s mistakes" %mistakes_made
            print "sorry, that is not in the word"
        letters_guessed.append(letter_choice)
        guesses +=1
        print "you have made %s guesses" %guesses
        word_guessed()

    while word_guessed() is True:
        print "Congratulations! You win :)"
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't recalculate `guesses_left`. At the start of each iteration you must do `guesses_left = MAX_GUESSES - guesses`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `guesses_left = MAX_GUESSES - guesses` inside of the `while word_guessed() is False:` loops. As it is now, you're setting `guesses_left = MAX_GUESSES - guesses` when `guesses == 0`, and then only changing `guesses` inside the loop. That will leave `guesses_left` unchanged.